# How to execute junit fail method successfully

Tags: junit

```
public class CalculatorTest extends TestCase
{
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    public void testAdd()
    {
        int a = 3;

        if(a==3)
            fail("Faieled as a is 3");
    }
}
```

Hi 
when i execute this , the Testcase is failed under Junit .
Basically what i want is when this condition `(a==3) matches  (true )` then
the method should fail and junit should show pass result ( Green color , in eclipse )

Comment: junit cannot fail and show green, both states are completely opposite. fail is red and pass is green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried replacing `fail("Failed as is 3");` with `assertTrue(true);`
That should give you a pass.

Comment: Thank you very much , i have a question then when should we use fail ??

Comment: I have honestly never used fail before. If you want to make sure a test fails, then use fail(). Other than that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Use `fail` when you know that the test failed without having to do a check (because you already are in an else block for example).

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
if(a == 3) {
   return;
 } else {
       fail();
 }
```

what you want to do ?

Comment: what class does fail method belong to?

Answer (score 0):

If the method returns, it will pass the test, so simply return